# Could you correct this translation from English To Korean?

Tags: translation

**Could you correct this translation from English To Korean?**

-Speaking English 15 Hours to 30 Hours a week with Native Speakers

-Very Affordable

-An Alternative to International Kindergarten

-Call 09... (English/Vietnamese)

---

-원어민과 함께 영어 말하기 15 시간에서 30 시간

-매우 저렴한

-국제 유치원의 대안

-전화 09... (영어 / 베트남어)

Comment: Hi Tom. Welcome - be sure to either accept the answer that is the solution, or leave a comment that explains why this solution can't be accepted, please.

Answer (score 1):

- 원어민과 영어로 주당 15~30시간 대화하기
- 매우 저렴함 or 매우 저렴한 가격 (very affordable price)
- 국제 유치원의 대안 seems fine, but I think the name 영어 유치원 is more commonly used.
- 09...로 전화하세요!